# Pinterest article rich pins logo not showing

Tags: html, pinterest

We've created a Business account in Pinterest and our website got approved. On approval, a meta tag was given and we added it to our website meta tags. We've validated our website URL for rich pins and it also got approved. Next step was to enable rich pins and we did it. The problem is that our logo doesn't appear in the article rich pin.

**This is what we have:**

[image]

**This is what we want:**

[image]

As you can see CNN has a logo and a dialog for following them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logo here is a link to your Pinterest profile. It is a feature of confirming your website, and not a feature of adding Rich Pin meta data to your site.
Learn about confirming your website at https://business.pinterest.com/confirm-your-website

The Follow button will appear to anyone who is not already following you. You can edit the image by changing your profile picture.

Pinterest does not currently add the favicon from your site to Rich Pins, but the validator does still check for it. It's used in embedded Pins on other sites currently, and the use may change in the future.

I hope that helps explain what you're seeing!

Comment: As I've said we've started the confirmation and the link that comes as an outcome of the confirmation is in the website.

Comment: The link you saw without your profile picture means that the site was not confirmed. It's a link to a source page, and all unconfirmed domains have this. I've replied to your specific issue on the open support ticket you have.

Comment: Thanks Darcie, we've added it to the main main page and it started working!

Comment: @toshkinl if Darcie has solved this then please use the Accept answer option to mark or as solved.